# Issues running javascript file with node.exe

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, visual-studio

I have a javascript file that receives data from an application and writes it into a text file.

Normally, if I type node vib_NK.js in the command prompt, it does receives the data and write it into the text file like it is supposed to do.

However, when I put the code (below) in a button which is in my form to start the node.exe with the javascript file. It did receive data but did not write it into a text file.

Why is this so?

```
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"F:\Users\153307D\Documents\vib_NK.js";
        process.Start();
```

Javascript code

```
buffer = new Buffer(FileOutput);
fs.open("SensorDataValue.txt",'a+' , function(err, fd) { 
  if(err) {
    throw 'error opening file: ' + err;
  }
  fs.write(fd, buffer, 0, buffer.length, null, function(err) {
    if (err) throw 'error writing file: ' + err;
    fs.close(fd, function() {
      console.log("V 14 The file was saved!");
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: How are you writing into a text file in your .js ? Can you post that code part?

Comment: @caner Hi, I already edited above with my code in my .js

Comment: Can you winform app create a text file in that folder?

Comment: Where are you looking at for your file? `fs.writeFile('C:\\Users\\Haikal\\Desktop\\demo.txt', 'log log log', function(err){
 if(err){
  return console.log(err);
 }

 console.log("File created");`
});' Can you test with this code?